# How to create customized login component in Salesforce?

Tags: authentication, salesforce, components, logout, apex

I understand that we can create a customized login page in Salesforce; but I should create a login component and embed it in our public pages. I  should also create another component that allows the user to log out or log in as as a different user. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% clear on the exact question here, but you don't need to create any custom components in order to customise the login page. This is now standard with Winter '14 - go to the "My Domain" admin menu item and scroll down to "Login Page Branding".

If you're unable to use this for some reason, or it's not what you're after perhaps you could explain further what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Will, I am aware of that feature. Problem is, based on our UI design I cannot dedicate a page to Login. I should rather embed some markup to our pages that should allow our website users to enter their username and password and login. To be clear, that login component will be part of right rail of our page template.

Comment: Understood - then I think you might want to check out the Force.com sites login page doc: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Authenticating_Users_on_Force.com_Sites

Comment: Thank you Will! I ended up using Site.Login method and it works. The form should have forceSSL="true" attribute, otherwise authentication will fail.